# Problema con código PHP

Tags: php

He programado lo siguiente... Estoy probando el código y al pulsar el botón "**Listado de participantes**"(al final del código) no se envía nada.
¿Como podría arreglarlo?

He probado a poner el código de la función "**participantes**" únicamente en una página y ha funcionado sin problemas.

Supongo que el problema estará en el evento `onclick` pero le he dado muchas vueltas y no se como solucionarlo ya que el ponerlo en otra página no me serviría.

Un saludo y muchas gracias.

```
<?php
$codigo = $_GET['s_competition_code'];

$servername1 = "localhost";
$database1 = "ianseo";
$username1 = "root";
$password1 = "";

$conn1 = mysqli_connect("localhost", "ianseo", "ianseo", "ianseo");

if (!$conn1) {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$localid = mysqli_query($conn1,"SELECT ToId FROM tournament WHERE ToCode= '$codigo' ");
mysqli_close($conn1);
?>
        <table>
            <thead><tr><th width="20%"></th><th></th></tr></thead>
            <tr><td>Listado de participantes</td><td colspan="2" class="SweCenter"><input type="submit" onClick="participantes();" style="padding: 5px; margin: 5px;" value="Publicar" /></td></tr>

        </table>
<script>

    function participantes() {
    alert('<?php 
        $servername1 = "localhost";
        $database1 = "ianseo";
        $username1 = "root";
        $password1 = "";

        $conn1 = mysqli_connect("localhost", "ianseo", "ianseo", "ianseo");
        // Verificar conexion
        if (!$conn1) {
              die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }

        $sql1 = mysqli_query($conn1,"SELECT * FROM entries WHERE EnTournament= '$localid' ") or die ("Error: $sql1");
        $mostrar = mysqli_fetch_all($sql1,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

        $servername = "server";
        $database = "db";
        $username = "user";
        $password = "pass";

        $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

        if (!$conn) {
              die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }

        mysqli_query($conn,"DELETE FROM `asirio_Resultados`.`participantes` WHERE `participantes`.`code` = '$codigo'");
        foreach($mostrar as $campo=>$r)
            mysqli_query($conn,"
                INSERT INTO participantes (ID, code, Division, Clase, IDCLUB, nombre, apellidos, Licencia)
                    VALUES ('".$r['EnId']."', '".$codigo."', '".$r['EnDivision']."', '".$r['EnClass']."', '".$r['EnCountry']."', '".$r['EnName']."', '".$r['EnFirstName']."', '".$r['EnCode']."')
            ");?>'
    );};
</script>
```

Comment: Tu onclick ejecuta un alert.. con un string que seria codigo php?

Comment: Imagino que lo ha puesto por poner, igualmente, el alert le saldría con el código, cosas peores se han visto....

Comment: Entonces como lo soluciono? Simplemente cambio el type y ya?

Comment: Yo lo he probado y funciona con el cambio. No te olvides de marcar como respuesta. Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es el `type` del `input`, ponlo en `button`.

Al tener `submit`, manda la peticion y omite el resto.

Espero te sirva.

---

Quedaria asi:

```
<table>
    <thead>
       <tr>
          <th width="20%"></th>
          <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
       <td>Listado de participantes</td>
       <td colspan="2" class="SweCenter"><input type="input" onClick="participantes();" style="padding: 5px; margin: 5px;" value="Publicar" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Es el comportamiento natural, sin embargo, si no se requiere cambiar las propiedades del formulario, hay maneras de evitar este comportamiento natural con eventos javascript como el `onsubmit` o incluso en el `onclick` del input con algún `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: He cambiado el type del input y sigue sin hacer nada, sigue sin funcionar

Comment: @JavierCuencaMartín el preventDefault o stopPropagation no serviria para este caso, por que el destino del form es el mismo.

Comment: Entonces como me tendría que quedar el código?